# How much deviation from ideal gas does the air in a 'Room' show?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas, air, gas

First of all, I'm only concerned about air in a Room (room in our houses). Also, lets take room temperature to be $27^{\circ}$ C specifically.

My first question is, how much different is this gas (air in my room) from properties of real gas?
Is it very different? or is it almost similar to [ideal gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas) for most properties.

One specific property I am concerned about is, 'Most probable speed'.
Using a standard ideal gas equation, I got the value of Most Probable speed of air particles to be $414$ m/s. (Taking average [Molar mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_mass) of air = 29 g)

Now, will the Most Probable speed of air particles in my room be about the same? I.e. will most particles be travelling at about this speed? Or is there a big difference between my calculated speed and the real speed?

$$v_{mp} = \sqrt{\frac{2RT}{M}} = \sqrt{\frac{2kT}{m}}$$

$$v_{mp} = 1.41 \sqrt{\frac{kT}{m}}$$

Comment: Don’t you mean different from an ‘ideal gas’? The air in your room is undoubtedly a real gas.

Comment: Doesn't the most probable speed formula assume that all the gas molecules are identical? In air, they're not — you have around 80% nitrogen and 20% oxygen.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes. Does this 'mixture' becomes a 'big' cause of deviation from ideal gas? Or it doesn't have that big of an impact?

Comment: @Rohit: That depends on what you consider "big". For the difference between nitrogen and an ideal gas at room temperature, I'd expect the difference to be really tiny. But because you are using air instead of nitrogen, the difference will be in the range of one or two percent.

Comment: Wow! I was going to allow for 10% difference. 1-2% is Great. So basically I can think about Air, when I try to imagine Ideal Gas and its concepts.

Comment: @PeterShor Will the Most probable speed of Air be very close to 414m/s as well?

Answer (score 2):

At room conditions, the ideal gas law furnishes an excellent approximation to the actual behavior of room air. Significant deviations from ideal behavior occur for example when the air pressure & density are so great that the volumes occupied by the molecules themselves must be taken into account when writing the equation of state. So: yes, room air is "ideal".

To find out when the ideal gas law begins to break down, look up "ideal gas law" on the interwebs and you will find a collection of modified versions of the law for use in extreme conditions.

Comment: So I can take the 'room air' as a good physical representative of ideal gas. So that I can think/visualise/imagine the 'air in room', when trying to understand the physical significance of various concepts and equations about ideal gas???

Comment: Also, can you tell me at around what Temprature and around what Pressure does ideal gas equations start giving horrendous results?

Comment: will edit with more info for you!

Comment: @nielsnielsen You may simply use

$$Z = \frac{p}{\rho R_\text{specific} T},$$

an check you much it deviates from $Z=1$.

Comment: @nielsnielsen Can you confirm that Most Probable Speed will also be close go the calculated value 414m/s for air (at given conditions).

Comment: no I can't! try posting that as a separate question. -NN